# SharePoint top level content links showing on the quick launch

Tags: 2013, navigation, quick-launch

I have created a sub-site which K but my problem is that I see site contents on my quick launch that is on the top level site which I do not need on my sub-site, how can I remove the contents from parent-site...
have followed this but no luck.

Go to the site settings of your subsite and find Navigation link in Look and Feel section. 
 In Current Navigation settings select Display the same navigation items as the parent site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your subsite go to site settings -> Navigation
And on second option "Current navigation" select the last option like in hte image below:
[image: Subsite's navigation settings]

Comment: thank you martusha,this was very helpfull straight to the point

Answer (score 0):

The answer lays here

> In Current Navigation settings select Display the same navigation items as the parent site

That is the opposite of what you want to do! You want it to only show items for the current site right?

Then you need to switch to

> Display the current site, the navigation items below the current site, and the current site's siblings

Comment: thank you Hardik , Robert your answer was very helpfull.

Comment: if an answer is helpful, you are supposed to upvote it and / or mark it as your accepted a answer